# Matlab - Creating two arrays that consider all possible values for two objects

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two physical "objects." I am representing their positions with two different arrays.

• Object 1 moves in the xy-plane only

• Object 2 moves in all three physical dimensions

**Objective:** Vectorize the four `for` loops without distorting the data. Also, the intent is to perform this operation for all possible values of object 1 to be compared with object 2.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Npos = 21;
Nsam = 200;

% dummy initialisation    
AX = rand(1, Npos);
AY = zeros(1, Npos);
AZ = rand(1, Npos);
Bx = rand(Nsam);
By = rand(Nsam);
Bz = rand(Nsam);

for qx = 1 : Npos
    for yx = 1 : Npos
        for zx = 1 : Nsam
            for cx = 1 : Nsam
                Tx2Array( qx, yx, zx, cx ) = sqrt( ( AX( qx ) - Bx( zx, cx ) ).^2 + ( AY( yx ) - By( zx, cx ) ).^2 + ( AZ( yx ) - Bz( zx, cx ) ).^2 );
            end
        end
    end
end
% Result is a 21 x 21 x 200 x 200 matrix filled with all real numbers
```

**Legend**

AX, AY, AZ are 1 x 21 arrays and represent the (x,y=0,z) of Object 1

AY is all zeros, but for readability is still included (hence no fifth loop!)

Bx, By, Bz are all 200 x 200 arrays and represent the (x,y,z) of Object 2

Npos = 21; Nsam = 200;

The formula used above is:

```
sqrt( (a1-b1)^2 + (a2-b2)^2 + (a3-b3)^2 )
```

Comment: It may be useful to provide a [mcve], i.e. initialise all variables (with random values)

Comment: The first thing you want to do it to preallocate `Tx2Array`. i.e. write: `Tx2Array = zeros(Npos,Npos,Nsam,Nsam)` before your loops.

Comment: Yes, but vector operations would not require pre-allocation.

Comment: I don't understand the dimensions of your inputs, but it seems to me that you can do the whole thing with `ndgrid` and `pdist2`.

Comment: @beaker, I have never used those functions before. Could you create an answer to expand upon them?

Comment: As I said, I don't understand your inputs. You've got `1 x 21` arrays that represent Object 1 somehow. Do these correspond to 21 possible positions for Object 1? How does that relate to the `200 x 200` arrays for Object 2?

Comment: I made the edit. They are 21 positions for each x,y,z for object 1, then there are 200 x 200 = 40,000 x,y,z positions for object 2.

Comment: Thank you m7913d for the edit. Thank you @beaker and m7913d for the good answers and sticking through this problem with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox available, you can use [pdist2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) to calculate the distance between each coordinate for Object 1 and each coordinate for Object 2:

```
[X1, Z1] = ndgrid(AX(:), AZ(:));   % X1 and Z1 will be 21x21
D = pdist2([X1(:), zeros(size(X1(:))), Z1(:)], [Bx(:), By(:), Bz(:)]);
```

The output in this case will be a `441 x 40,000` array where `D(i, j)` gives you the distance between point `i` of Object 1 and point `j` of Object 2, both using linear indexing.

Comment: Isn't the result suppose to resemble the number of computations as 21 x 21 x 200 x 200 = 17,640,000 elements total? In this case, there are only 21 x 40,000 = 840,000 elements.

Comment: You have only 21 points for Object 1, right? and 40,000 points for Object 2? This is why I was getting confused with your math, because it seems to me that you're either double-counting the points for Object 1 or only counting a third of the points for Object 2.

Comment: I agree with beaker that this calculation seems to be more logical. If you have 21 A points and 40 000 B points, one can calculate 21 x 40 000 distances. You are calculating the distances to all possible permutations of A, which may be what you want, but is often not the case.

Comment: There are 21 'x-coordinates' and 21 'z-coordinates' for Object 1. As stated, it exists only in the xz-plane. This means that the object will exist at times along the x-axis, but may also exist along the z-axis and in between both.

Comment: But those 21 x-coordinates and 21 z-coordinates only correspond to 21 points, correct? Or are you making a grid of all x- and z- coordinate possibilities?

Comment: Correct, imagine them together as 21 x 21. So if you take a look and the nested `for` loops, only the AX and AZ (because AY = 0) are used correspondingly with qx and yx.

Comment: We can also reshape the resulting array if you really want it to be `21x21x200x200`.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that! However, I am not familiar with how the reshape function works. I'm trying to maintain integrity of the data.

Comment: Well, why don't you calculate the `Tx2Array` using your code, then use this and `reshape(D, 21, 21, 200, 200)` and compare them?

Comment: I just verified the data as @m7913d did in his/her answer. It works fine and the graphs appear to come out the same. Thanks for the assistance. I knew there was an easier way to do it, I just don't know the functions available to us through MATLAB yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the to inner loops by replacing `zx` and `cx` with `:` as follows:

```
Tx2Array = zeros(Npos, Npos, Nsam, Nsam); % preallocate memory
for qx = 1 : Npos
    for yx = 1 : Npos
        Tx2Array( qx, yx, :, : ) = sqrt( ( AX( qx ) - Bx( :, : ) ).^2 + ( AY( yx ) - By( :, : ) ).^2 + ( AZ( yx ) - Bz( :, : ) ).^2 );
    end
end
```

In this way, the largest dimensions are vectorised. So, the largest improvement is already done.

By converting your `B*` to 4D and generating a mesh for your `A*` matrices, you can even remove all the for loops as follows:

```
[AX_, AZ_] = meshgrid(AX, AZ);
AX_ = AX_';
AZ_ = AZ_';
AY_ = zeros(Npos);

Bx_(1, 1, :, :) = Bx;
By_(1, 1, :, :) = By;
Bz_(1, 1, :, :) = Bz;

Tx2Array2 = sqrt( ( AX_ - Bx_ ).^2 + ( AY_ - By_ ).^2 + ( AZ_ - Bz_ ).^2 );
```

You can check the the results are the same using the following check:

```
max(max(max(max(abs(Tx2Array - Tx2Array2))))) < eps
```

Comment: you can remove the `(:,:)` from the `B`s

Comment: I know, I just want to make explicit what I have done, i.e. replace `zx` and `cx` with `:`

Comment: Thanks! that does bring it down to two loops.

Comment: I think you might get in trouble with floating point comparisons on your last line. You might want to change it to `< eps`.

Comment: @beaker It was not a problem (on my pc), but I changed it because it is always good practice to take floating point precision into account when comparing floating point numbers

Comment: Okay, I only mentioned it because the last comment in the OP's code says they're using real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are correctly initialized your task will be very simple:

Initialize the arrays with the correct dimensions

```
AX = rand( Npos,1);
AY = zeros(1, Npos);
AZ = rand(1, Npos);
Bx = rand(1,1,Nsam,Nsam);
By = rand(1,1,Nsam,Nsam);
Bz = rand(1,1,Nsam,Nsam);
```

Then in MATLAB r2016b / Octave you can simply write:

```
Tx2Array = sqrt( ( AX - Bx ).^2 + ( AY - By ).^2 + ( AZ - Bz ).^2 );
```

In pre r2016b you can use [bsxfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
Tx2Array = sqrt(bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@minus,AX , Bx).^2,bsxfun(@minus,AY , By).^2),bsxfun(@minus,AZ , Bz).^2));
```